# many-to-many: has_many :through and User table relation issue in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through

My setup for the models:

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

In my application LogedIn-User IS A either doctor,patient or the Admin i got understand that how Doctor and patient relationship work with appointment,But how to setup the user model and table for that

```
class User_type < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctors, class_name: "USER"
  belongs_to :patients, class_name: "USER"
end
```

I know that I am missing crucial self association here but how can i do that, or any other way to set up these models and tables for that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :doctor
  has_one :patient
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

Hope this will work for you, If you understand many to many relationship properly.

Comment: Doctor or patient they them self are user.so between them how can be has many-belongs_to relationship is possible?

Comment: User is only user whether he/she is Doctor or patient.
both will belong to user.

Comment: then how would login user know his role ?

Comment: and what about doctors and patients please tell me how would i do that?

Comment: if you still have issue come on Skype: ahmadhasankhan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586329/ruby-on-rails-with-different-user-types

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in here: `class User_type < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs-to :doctors, class_name: "USER"
  belongs_to :patients, class_name: "USER"
end`

it should be `belongs_to`, you sure thats not your problem?

Comment: I corrected typo, but my actual question here  is about the model and table if User(s),how it look like